# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, python-venv

Im currently having issues importing modules in my venv on vscode for google cloud firestore.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

pip -V shows python 3.8.
python -V shows Python 3.8.1.
using pip freeze, the module appears here.

```
firebase-admin==5.0.3
```

however it returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'
```

ive tried`from google.cloud import firestore` as well but it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'`

any help here?

Comment: Did you install the modules in the correct virtual environment?

Comment: It should be! I've checked with pip show firebase-admin and it shows that it is installed in the venv folder

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by running in python terminal. Somehow using run code in python results in this error. Could possibly be due to interpeter configuration issues